# Storing Apache Hadoop Data Output to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, database-connection, bigdata

I need to store output of map-reduce program into database, so is there any way?

If so, is it possible to store output into multiple columns & tables based on requirement??

please suggest me some solutions.

Thank you..

Comment: Check this out: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/  Specifically the section of 'Writing results back to the database'

Comment: YOu can use [`Sqoop`](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html) to transfer data to and fro

Comment: Thak you Amar for your link & SuvP..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The great example is shown [on this blog](http://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/database-access-with-apache-hadoop/), I tried it and it goes really well. I quote the most important parts of the code.

At first, you must create a class representing data you would like to store. The class must implement DBWritable interface:

```
public class DBOutputWritable implements Writable, DBWritable
{
   private String name;
   private int count;

   public DBOutputWritable(String name, int count) {
     this.name = name;
     this.count = count;
   }

   public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {   }

   public void readFields(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
     name = rs.getString(1);
     count = rs.getInt(2);
   }

   public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {    }

   public void write(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
     ps.setString(1, name);
     ps.setInt(2, count);
   }
}
```

Create objects of previously defined class in your Reducer:

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, DBOutputWritable, NullWritable> {

   protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context ctx) {
     int sum = 0;

     for(IntWritable value : values) {
       sum += value.get();
     }

     try {
       ctx.write(new DBOutputWritable(key.toString(), sum), NullWritable.get());
     } catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } catch(InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Finally you must configure a connection to your DB (do not forget to add your db connector on the classpath) and register your mapper's and reducer's input/output data types.

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf,
     "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",   // driver class
     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb", // db url
     "user",    // username
     "password"); //password

     Job job = new Job(conf);
     job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
     job.setMapperClass(Map.class); // your mapper - not shown in this example
     job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class); // your mapper - not shown in this example
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); // your mapper - not shown in this example
     job.setOutputKeyClass(DBOutputWritable.class); // reducer's KEYOUT
     job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);   // reducer's VALUEOUT
     job.setInputFormatClass(...);
     job.setOutputFormatClass(DBOutputFormat.class);

     DBInputFormat.setInput(...);

     DBOutputFormat.setOutput(
     job,
     "output",    // output table name
     new String[] { "name", "count" }   //table columns
     );

     System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
   }
}
```