# Is there a way where the output of the MapReduce job is imported into SQL table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Is there a way where the output of the MapReduce job is imported into SQL table?

I want to know if we could automatically import the output of MapReduce job (MapReduce job should be responsible for exporting ) into SQL table (MySQL,Oracle, etc..).

I know Sqoop could be used as a tool but could it be used in MR job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351475/storing-apache-hadoop-data-output-to-mysql-database has an accepted answer for doing this with MySQL as the target database.

Comment: Many thanks mc110 for the link :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you write in the reducer some code that instead of writing the output to the context, it connects via JDBC to the SQL table and insert it (which would be a really BAD idea), the only thing you can do is to use Oozie to automate the execution of the MapReduce job and then perform the insertion using Sqoop. Oozie is a workflow scheduler to automate all these kinds of operations. You can find more information about it [here](https://oozie.apache.org/).

Comment: Many thanks Balduz for sharing some useful information.